# evaluation of an abstract type member

Tags: scala

Why this code won't compile? Tested on Scala 2.13.6. Is there a way to let scalac know that `SizeOfType[Unit]#Size` is actually `Short`?

```scala
trait SizeOfType[T] {
  type Size
  def getSize(): Size
}

object SizeOfType {
  implicit def unit: SizeOfType[Unit] = new SizeOfType[Unit] {
    type Size = Short
    def getSize(): Short = 0
  }

  def test(implicit ev: SizeOfType[Unit]): Short = ev.getSize()
}
```

```
[error] type mismatch;
[error]  found   : ev.Size
[error]  required: Short
[error]   def test(implicit ev: SizeOfType[Unit]): Short = ev.getSize()
```

Comment: The type variable T doesn't occur in the trait definition; I think you could get rid of it.

Comment: You're using the name SizeOfType twice. If we call the object `SizeOfTypeOb`, we can just write `object SizeOfTypeOb extends SizeOfType {type Size = Short; val x: Short = 2}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When parameterising with type members instead of type parameters you have to provide *type refinement* when asking for type class instance, otherwise you are only asking Scala for

```
SizeOfType[Unit]
```

and not the intended

```
SizeOfType[Unit] { type Size = Short }
```

so something like

```
implicit val unit: SizeOfType[Unit] { type Size = Short } =
  new SizeOfType[Unit] {
    type Size = Short
    def getSize(): Short = 0
  }

def test(implicit ev: SizeOfType[Unit] { type Size = Short }): Short = ev.getSize()
val x: Short = test // ok
```

Usually you would create dependently typed method and then you can avoid type refinement in the method definition (but it is still needed for definition of type class instance)

```
implicit val unit: SizeOfType[Unit] { type Size = Short } = ???
def test(implicit ev: SizeOfType[Unit]): ev.Size = ev.getSize()
val x: Short = test // ok
```

I would suggested studying through "Chapter 4, Working with types and implicits" of [underscoreio/shapeless-guide](https://github.com/underscoreio/shapeless-guide), in particular section which mentions

> ...If we define the return type as `Second[L]`, the `Out` type member
> will be erased from the return type and the type class will not work
> correctly.

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no way.

Think about what would happen if you call `test` with another implicit value of type `SizeOfType[Unit]` which defines `type Size = Int`.

Or said differently, the method `test` can only infer types based on the trait definition of `SizeOfType`, not on one actual implicit value content.

You could however define `test` as returning the type `ev.Size`.